# Removing numerically named files with more than n decimal places

Tags: bash, files, delete

I have data files named by a time step such as:

```
0.01  
0.02  
0.03  
0.04  
0.05  
0.06  
0.07  
0.08  
0.09  
0.1  
0.11
...
0.99
1
1.01
...
1000
```

As you can see, some data file names have two digits after the decimal place, while others have 1 or no decimal places.  I only want to remove the files that have 2 decimal place names (e.g. 0.01, 0.02, etc) while keeping all the files that have fewer than 2 decimal places.  So in the end, I want to keep the file labeled as:

```
0.1
0.2
...
0.9
1
1.1
...
1000
```

but remove the rest.

How can I remove numerically named files with fewer than n decimal places?

Comment: easily: `rm *.??`

Comment: or specifically `rm *.[0-9][0-9]`

Comment: @glennjackman That will also remove `.12` for example (zero digits on the integer part) of which nothing has been said and also any string before the letter: `MyImportantMusic.22`. Better stick to safer patterns, use `+([0-9]).[0-9][0-9]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking.  You ask both to *remove* files with fewer than 2 digits after the decimal and to *keep* files with fewer than 2 digits after the decimal.

Assuming you're using the bash shell.  Answer will change for different shells.

If you want to **remove** all files with fewer than 2 digits after the decimal:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(*.[0-9][0-9])
```

If you want to **keep** all files with fewer than 2 digits after the decimal:

```
rm *.[0-9][0-9]
```

Comment: My question clearly states: "I only want to remove the files that have 2 decimal place names (e.g. 0.01, 0.02, etc) while keeping all the files that have fewer than 2 decimal places".   Please explain how I could have made this more clear.

Comment: @don_crissti: Ah.  Now I understand the confusion.  Thank you for letting me know.  I'll fix the title accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
$ rm +([0-9]).[0-9][0-9]
```

Will remove all files with one (or more) digits before the dot and exactly two decimals.

That should run in bash as the extglog is set by default for interactive shells, but if you need to use it in a script, use this:

```
shopt -s extglog
rm +([0-9]).[0-9][0-9]
```